# How to pass a custom object from an activity class to a repository class using Dagger2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger, android-viewmodel

This is how I'm observing data in `MyActivity class:

```
@Module
public class MyActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {
    @Inject MyViewModelFactory factory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addData();
    }

    public void addData() {
        //How to pass this custom object to ViewModel???
        CustomClass obj = new CustomClass("CustomData");
        MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MyViewModel.class);
        LiveData<Data> liveData = viewModel.getLiveData();
        liveData.observe(this, this);
    }
}
```

This my `ModelFactory` class:

```
@Singleton
public class MyViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators;

    @Inject
    MyViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> creators) {
        this.creators = creators;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
        if (creator == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                    creator = entry.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (creator == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
        }

        try {
            return (T) creator.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `ViewModel` class:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<Data> dataLiveData;
    private MyRepository repository;

    @Inject
    MyViewModel(MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        //I need it here!!!
        dataLiveData = repository.addDataToLiveData(obj);
    }

    LiveData<Data> getLiveData() {
        return dataLiveData;
    }
}
```

And this is my `Repository` class:

```
@Singleton
public class MyRepository {
    private MyApi myApi;

    @Inject
    MyRepository(MyApi myApi) {
        this.myApi = myApi;
    }

    LiveData<Data> addDataToLiveData(CustomClass obj) {
        myApi.getData(obj); //Make Api call and use obj
    }
}
```

How to pass that `CustomClass` object from `MyActivity` to the `ViewModel` class?

Comment: Why can't you just pass it in a function?

Comment: As I commented to your answer, is always `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function in ViewModel that accepts your CustomClass object, and call that function from Activity.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<Data> dataLiveData;
    private MyRepository repository;


    @Inject
    MyViewModel(MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    LiveData<Data> getLiveData() {
        return dataLiveData;
    }

    public void setCustomObject(CustomObject customObj){
       repository.addDataToLiveData(obj);

    }
}
```

**EDIT**: To fix your error:

```
 public void addData() {
        //How to pass this custom object to ViewModel???
        CustomClass obj = new CustomClass("CustomData");
        MyViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MyViewModel.class);
        //ADD IT HERE
        viewModel.setCustomObj(obj);
        LiveData<Data> liveData = viewModel.getLiveData();
        liveData.observe(this, this);
    }
```

Comment: I already did this and call `setCustomObject(obj)` in the `MyActivity` but I always get `NullPointerException` at line `dataLiveData = repository.addDataToLiveData(obj);`. So `obj` is `null`.

Comment: @LilianSorlanski because you are adding it in Constructor, when constructor is called the object is null, Add it to livedata from function instead

Comment: @LilianSorlanski Call this function from your **addData** function **right after** creating object of viewmodel.

Comment: You are right life saver, works perfect! Thank you so much!